# Xamarin.Forms: Create instance of a DataTemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I wan't to create a `ContentView` with a `BindableProperty` of type `DataTemplate`, so that when I use my custom `ContentView` i can customize how the elements should look like.

But I wan't to arrange and create the contents in code, how can I create an instance from a DataTemplate?

For example, in my custom view, I have a collection of objects, now for each object I want to create a view based on the set data template and set the binding context of that created view to that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out in following way.

I use my custom `ContentView` in following way:

```
        <controls:MyCustomView Items="{Binding SampleItems}">
            <controls:MyCustomView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SampleProperty}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:MyCustomView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:MyCustomView>
```

then in the code behind of the `MyCustomView` I declare a `ItemTemplate` bindable property:

```
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(ItemTemplate),
        typeof(DataTemplate),
        typeof(MyCustomView),
        propertyChanged: (bObj, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            var view = bObj as MyCustomView;
            if (view != null)
                view.SampleMethodToArrangeItems();
        }
    );
```

now let's say that in the `SampleMethodToArrangeItems` method I want to create and arrange, the items created from the provided data template:

```
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var itemView = ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
            if (itemView != null)
            {
                itemView.BindingContext = item;
                // Do something with the create view e.g. add it to Grid.Children
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the complete working renderer of it? its a bit confusing to understand...Thanks in advance